# How to define very simple own rule in fuseki step by step?

Tags: jena, fuseki, swrl, apache-jena, jena-rules

I'm asking your help to understand how to create my own property rules in fuseki.
I've read the documentation of Jena and Fuseki about reasoners and rules but I don't understand how to create (step by step) simple rules. And the examples that I've found are focus on OWL reasoners.

I don't clearly understand what write in the config.ttl file in order to fuseki takes into account my rules on my ontology. I use the Sparql point with python through a sparql-client, and I don't master java code and applications.

My purpose is to create the next rules:

```
@prefix rdf: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
@prefix ex: http://example.com/
@prefix xs: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#
@prefix ont: http://www.myownontolongy/ontology/

[dependsOfExchange:
(?e ont:refersToPriorActivityData ?a)
(?a ont:hasExchange ?es)
->
(?e rme:dependsOfExchange ?es)
]
```

The principle in SWRL syntax is:

```
refersToPriorActivityData(?e,?a) ^ hasExchange(?a,?es) => dependsOfExchange(?e,?es)
```

Thanks in advance.

---

### EDIT with one solution

```
@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .
tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
tdb:GraphTDB    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
   # Timeout - server-wide default: milliseconds.
   # Format 1: "1000" -- 1 second timeout
   # Format 2: "10000,60000" -- 10s timeout to first result, then 60s timeout for the rest of query.
   # See java doc for ARQ.queryTimeout
   # ja:context [ ja:cxtName "arq:queryTimeout" ;  ja:cxtValue "10000" ] ;

   # ja:loadClass "your.code.Class" ;

   fuseki:services (
     <#reminer>
   ) .

## ---------------------------------------------------------------
## Updatable in-memory dataset.

<#reminer> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    # URI of the dataset -- http://host:port/reminer
    fuseki:name                        "name_of_your_database" ; 
    fuseki:serviceQuery                "sparql" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery                "query" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpdate               "update" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpload               "upload" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore  "data" ;     
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore       "get" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore       "" ;      
    fuseki:dataset                     <#myDataset> ;
    .

## In-memory, initially empty.
## This database set-up allows OWL inference.
<#myDataset> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset ;
                tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ; 
                ja:defaultGraph <#infGraph> .

<#infGraph> rdf:type ja:InfModel ;
             ja:reasoner [ ja:rulesFrom <file:rules/inference_rules.rules> ; ] ; #the rules directory is in the "run" directory
             ja:baseModel <#baseGraph> .

<#baseGraph> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB;
             tdb:location "path_of_your_database" .
```

And the inference_rules.rules for an example:

```
@prefix rdf: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
@prefix ex: http://example.com/
@prefix xs: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#
@prefix mO: http://www.semanticweb.org/myOntology/

[dependsOfExchange:
(?e mO:producedBy ?a)
(?a mO:hasExchange ?es)
                 ->
                 (?e rme:dependsOf ?es)
         ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .ttl use through the cmd line: ./fuseki-server --config=/path/of/your/custom-config.ttl

```
@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .
tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
tdb:GraphTDB    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
   # Timeout - server-wide default: milliseconds.
   # Format 1: "1000" -- 1 second timeout
   # Format 2: "10000,60000" -- 10s timeout to first result, then 60s timeout for the rest of query.
   # See java doc for ARQ.queryTimeout
   # ja:context [ ja:cxtName "arq:queryTimeout" ;  ja:cxtValue "10000" ] ;

   # ja:loadClass "your.code.Class" ;

   fuseki:services (
     <#reminer>
   ) .

## ---------------------------------------------------------------
## Updatable in-memory dataset.

<#reminer> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    # URI of the dataset -- http://host:port/reminer
    fuseki:name                        "name_of_your_database" ; 
    fuseki:serviceQuery                "sparql" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery                "query" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpdate               "update" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpload               "upload" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore  "data" ;     
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore       "get" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore       "" ;      
    fuseki:dataset                     <#myDataset> ;
    .

## In-memory, initially empty.
## This database set-up allows OWL inference.
<#myDataset> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset ;
                tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ; 
                ja:defaultGraph <#infGraph> .

<#infGraph> rdf:type ja:InfModel ;
             ja:reasoner [ ja:rulesFrom <file:rules/inference_rules.rules> ; ] ; #the rules directory is in the "run" directory
             ja:baseModel <#baseGraph> .

<#baseGraph> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB;
             tdb:location "path_of_your_database" .
```

And the inference_rules.rules for an example:

```
@prefix rdf: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
@prefix ex: http://example.com/
@prefix xs: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#
@prefix mO: http://www.semanticweb.org/myOntology/

[dependsOfExchange:
(?e mO:producedBy ?a)
(?a mO:hasExchange ?es)
                 ->
                 (?e rme:dependsOf ?es)
         ]
```

Comment: Do you know how to use string content directly in the assemble instead of use <file:// ...> ?